# PHP IMAP Starting Noob Help?

Tags: php, imap

So, for experimental purposes, I want to learn how to use IMAP in PHP. I'm not sure where to start- like I don't know how to even make a user or login on a server. If someone knows anything that could help get me started, I would greatly appreciate it. :)

Comment: By "use IMAP," do you mean "send emails using IMAP?"

Comment: Kind of- I want to make my own email client in the end. If you know of any good tutorial sites, I'd be more than happy to check them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a coding example, as well as all the IMAP functions available on the php.net site:

http://php.net/imap

David Walsh here has posted how to get gMail IMAP information

http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap